# Create list of all files within a folder where one of a number of IDs are contained with the file dataframe, not the file name

Tags: r

I would like to have R return a list of all Excel files within a folder that contain one of a number of IDs within the file itself - I am not looking at filenames, for which list.files could be used. Below code sets the filepath and creates a list of the necessary IDs to search for, is there a simple way of having R loop through each file in the folder and return a list of files that have at least one matching ID within the data contained in the file itself, not the filename?

```
#Set filepath
MYFILEPATH <- "\\\\dcfnetwork\\data\\\\R\\Test Folder"

#set list of IDs to check for
IDList <- c("l21", "d66", "f53")
```

Comment: Could you walk through an example: say the first excel file is excel_file_1, then where in the excel file would the IDs for checking be located: anywhere or on a named worksheet in defined cells. Or are you asking that all worksheets and active cells are checked to confirm presence of an ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give your file paths to Escel files having at leat one id in at least one cell in at least one worksheet:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(readxl)

IDList <- c("l21", "d66", "f53")
names(IDList) <- IDList

data <-
  tibble(id = IDList) %>%
  expand_grid(file = list.files("files/", pattern = "xlsx?$", full.names = TRUE)) %>%
  mutate(
    # for all combos of id and file
    contains_id = map2_lgl(id, file, function(id, file) {
      # for all worksheets
      excel_sheets(file) %>%
        map(~ read_excel(file, sheet = .x)) %>%
        # tibble to text
        map(~ .x %>%
          as.character() %>%
          paste0(collapse = " ")) %>%
        # detect pattern
        map(~ .x %>% str_detect(id)) %>%
        # one occurrence in any sheet is sufficient
        any()
    })
  )
#> # A tibble: 6 x 3
#>   id    file              contains_id
#>   <chr> <chr>             <lgl>      
#> 1 l21   files//file1.xlsx FALSE      
#> 2 l21   files//file2.xlsx TRUE       
#> 3 d66   files//file1.xlsx FALSE      
#> 4 d66   files//file2.xlsx TRUE       
#> 5 f53   files//file1.xlsx TRUE       
#> 6 f53   files//file2.xlsx FALSE

data %>%
  filter(contains_id) %>%
  pull(file) %>%
  unique()
#> [1] "files//file1.xlsx" "files//file2.xlsx"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-11-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

### Example data

Sheet 2 of file1.xlsx:

```
x   y
f53 1
f53 2
```

Sheet 1 of file2.xlsx:

```
x   y
1   d66
2   l21
```

Comment: Thanks but I'm not looking for a list of filenames that match an ID in the IDList - I am looking for a list of filenames where an ID is within the Excel file itself, i.e. on a worksheet within each file. Your code would only look at file names rather than what is in the file, is that correct?

Comment: For example if file 'test1.xlsx' has value of 'd66' anywhere within any worksheet, I would like value text1.xlsx returned to the list, and so on and so forth for each file within the folder.

Comment: So not just a column name but any value in any cell containing character like `l21`?

Comment: Yes sorry if I wasn't clear - what I'm looking for is to return the file name is one of the IDs in IDList appears anywhere within any worksheet within each file.

Comment: @JeffWithpetersen I revised my answer

Comment: Amazing code, I know you're not supposed to thank on here necessarily but that is a great effort, thank you so much!